# Performance difference for loops in C++

Tags: c++, performance

Consider the following `C++` class and struct in

```
typedef struct MatrixDims
{
    int rows, cols;
} MatrixDims;

class Matrix 
{
private:
    float *_matrixElements;
    MatrixDims _matrixDims;
public:
    Matrix(int rows, int cols);
    ~Matrix();
    void printMatrix() const;
}
```

**Notes:**

1. I am using an *array* instead of a *vector* on purpose.
2. The class member `_matrixElements` is an array of `floats` created using `new`.
3. The matrix here is implemented using *1-dimentional* array.

**My question:**

Is there any *performance difference* between the two following implementations of the method `printMatrix()`?

```
void Matrix::printMatrix() const
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->_matrixDims.rows * this->_matrixDims.cols; i++) // (1)
    {
        cout << this->_matrixElements[i]; // (2)
    }
}

void Matrix::printMatrix() const
{
    size_t size = this->_matrixDims.rows * this->_matrixDims.cols; // (3)

    float *mat = this->_matrixElements; // (4)

    for (size_t i = 0; i < size; ++i) // (5)
    {
        cout << mat[i]; // (6)
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you find out when you measured them?

Comment: You ask this question as if there is some sort of certain way of measuring performance that independent of compiler and platform etc. If you want to know which of these two methods is better then time them on your machine with your compiler.

Comment: I would guess that there is no difference because 1) compilers are very good at optimising code, and 2) the time taken will be dominated by the I/O anyway. But I'm only guessing, if you want to know time it for yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all in `C` and `C++` there is "AS IF" rule. Here is some [SO answer about that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15718279/1387438).
This means that if you enable compiler optimizations there should be no significant differences.

In fact for such simple modification I wouldn't be surprised if final machine code is exactly same. So keep your code readable.

I did [compared both versions](https://godbolt.org/z/t4w42x) and fist version recalculates total size of matrix for each iteration. Compiler assumes that `rows` or `cols` values can change when `std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >::_M_insert<double>(double)` is called.
Note that this operation is quite fast so when you do  a measurement I doubt you will be able to measure any difference.

Comment: I see, so at the end I can avoid the size recalculation at each iteration, and the rest is not important as long as my code is readable, thanks

Comment: consider providing `begin` `end` and use range loop: https://godbolt.org/z/ZcnH5z